# Selenium twitter unable to take username and password

Tags: python, selenium, twitter

The following code is a segment of my program where I am trying to get followers of the screen_names given in excel file. Earlier my code was working fine, but now it gets stuck every time after loading twitter page on chrome. It does not enter username and password in browser. Please guide me on what could be wrong in the following code.

```
    *driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/name/sport/chromedriver')
        driver.get("https://twitter.com/download?logged_out=1&lang=en")
        time.sleep(6) 
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='signin-link']").click()
        time.sleep(3)
        pagecount=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='signin-email']").send_keys('mygmail')
        pagecount=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='signin-password']").send_keys('mypassword')
        time.sleep(3)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='signin-dropdown']/div[3]/form/input[1]").click()*


TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-d3a52c563a6e> in <module>()
     18 driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='signin-link']").click()
     19 time.sleep(3)
---> 20 pagecount=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='email']").send_keys('architgarg1515@gmail.com')
     21 pagecount=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='Password']").send_keys('@Kaminibruno05')
     22 time.sleep(3)

C:\Users\khushi.tiwari\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in find_element_by_xpath(self, xpath)
    256             driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div/td[1]')
    257         """
--> 258         return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
    259 
    260     def find_elements_by_xpath(self, xpath):

C:\Users\khushi.tiwari\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in find_element(self, by, value)
    710                 value = '[name="%s"]' % value
    711         return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT,
--> 712                              {'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
    713 
    714     def find_elements(self, by=By.ID, value=None):

C:\Users\khushi.tiwari\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    199         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    200         if response:
--> 201             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    202             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    203                 response.get('value', None))

C:\Users\khushi.tiwari\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    162 
    163         screen = None
--> 164         if 'screen' in value:
    165             screen = value['screen']
    166 

TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I look at Login form on `https://twitter.com/download?logged_out=1&lang=en` page, and I see no element with `@id='signin-email'` or `@id='signin-password'`. Instead I see login element as

```
<input type="text" class="text-input email-input js-signin-email" name="session[username_or_email]" autocomplete="username" placeholder="Phone, email or username">
```

and password as

```
<input type="password" class="text-input" name="session[password]" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="current-password">
```

So it means your xpath is wrong. Try

```
 pagecount=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@name,'username')]").send_keys('mygmail')
 pagecount=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@name,'password')]").send_keys('mypassword')
```

Also in the exception dump I believe you forgot to replace your real username/password, so you may want to change your password.

Comment: I solved it by looking at html page source code. But thank you so much for your answer

Answer (score 0):

I understand im answering this question too late.. Another simple solution for this is by using only more relevant part of the class name for username and password.

example:

```
     browser.find_element_by_class_name("js-username-field")
     browser.find_element_by_class_name("js-password-field")
```

It worked on me..